# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'job_description' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, html-table

*SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'job_description' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `jobs` (`job_title`, `job_description`, `file`, `note`) values (EEE, ?, user.JPG, KJL))*

**migration**

```
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
              $table->String('job_title');
                $table->String('job_description');
                  $table->String('file');
                    $table->String('note');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**model**

```
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [

        'job_title',
        'job_description',
        'file',
        'note',
    ];
```

**controller**

```
      Job::insert([
        'job_title'=>$request->job_title,
        'job_description'=>$request->job_description,
        'file'=>$request->file,
        'note'=>$request->note
      ]);
      return Redirect()->back()->with('success','Job added successfully');
    }
```

Comment: Add your form html/blade to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column job_description in the database is set up as NOT NULL constraints. And the value trying to set using $request->job_description with NULL. That is the root cause of this issue.

To rectify you can modify your controller like:

```
Job::insert([
        'job_title'=>$request->job_title,
        'job_description'=>(!is_null($request->job_description) ? $request->job_description : ""),
        'file'=>$request->file,
        'note'=>$request->note
      ]);
```

Or provide a default value for fields using `input()`

```
Job::insert([
    'job_title' => $request->job_title,
    'job_description' => $request->input('job_description', ''),
    'file' => $request->file,
    'note' => $request->note
]);
```

Comment: But I don't want to keep it nullable . I fill the job description field in the form . But it can not get any data that I inputed and give a output that it didn't receive any data

Comment: @NazmulAnik if you leave the input empty for the `job_description`, it will be `null` in the request object because of the default middleware `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`. If you are sure that you have data in your field, then i suggest you verify the `name="job_description"` on your input/textarea

Comment: It works. I did mistake in blade file form that you explained . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `nullable` for column declaration `$table->string('job_description')->nullable()`, if you want use it with null value.

Comment: But I don't want to keep it nullable . I fill the job description field in the form . But it can not get any data that I inputed and give a output that it didn't receive any data